# Disappearing Excel buttons

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I am seeing buttons disappear throughout Office programs - does anyone know why this may be happening? The first screenshot below is the VBE window when it first opens - if I drag a toolbar to a new location, all of its icons appear, but as soon as the mouse hovers over a button, the image disappears (though the button can still be clicked).

Other times when I open the VBE window, though, all of the buttons display correctly and do not disappear when the mouse cursor moves over them (not sure why this happens sometimes).

The other place I have noticed buttons disappearing is in the popup dialogs that appear when you copy/paste, for example. The buttons and drop-down choices exhibit the same behavior - some images are gone from the start (i.e. the initial pop-up button) and some disappear when the mouse moves over them (the dropdown choice buttons).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Update: I should add that the issue still appears when opening Excel, Word, etc. in Safe Mode - so the issue doesn't seem to be add-ins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have this problem quite frequently. My research turned up things like "print = true in the properties" (which I usually don't want), "take focus on click", etc. etc. The only thing I've found that works 100% for me (whether right, wrong or indifferent) is to do the following with each button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton10_Click()

 '__SEARCH FOR SOMETHING BY NAME__

    With Me.CommandButton10
     .Left = 860.5
     .Top = 47.25
     .Width = 50.25
     .Height = 25.5
    End With
  'The rest of your code goes here..
End Sub
```

I know it's a pain to do it this way, and every time you click a button it
resets itself to the position, but I haven't lost a button since I started doing this. Now I do every button I use like this. I too would accept a "proper" fix if someone could come up with one. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Thanks Mitch! This is a great suggestion for restoring ActiveX command buttons that have gone astray - do you have any idea how to restore the buttons that are missing in my screenshots? As far as I can tell, they are CommandBar objects that are somehow being changed or corrupted.

Comment: As far as I can gather, your issue is Office 2013 related. I found the following post on Microsoft's site. Look at the entry. It's the only one where someone discovered a fix (sort of). https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_winother/text-menu-names-buttons-disappear-re-appear-on/4462b72b-6568-4aba-967d-809db4b634b9?auth=1

Comment: You may experience these symptoms if you have a video configuration on your computer that is incompatible with the Office feature set that is responsible for displaying the application and for animations in the application.
The hardware acceleration function of the operating system relies on up-to-date and compatible display drivers.
Note: Hardware acceleration that uses the video card is always disabled when Office is running in a Remote Desktop session, and also when the application is started in safe mode. DISABLE HARDWARE ACCELERATION IN OFFICE

Comment: Thanks for the link, that makes a lot of sense. The computer I have that's experiencing these issues is a virtual desktop powered by VMWare, so there must be some kind of graphics issue similar to when Office is running in a Remote Desktop session - I'll give disabling the hardware acceleration a try.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an excel 2003 file but running it in excel 2007.  I have an issue where suddenly ALL the macro buttons (about 25) disappeared on one of the tabs in my spreadsheet.  Macros in the other tabs are not affected.  The macros disappear only from the one tab.  After several years of having to restore from a master file and update the data, I tried moving the macros (and changing the size slightly) that were on line 1 of the sheet (there are also macros further down the sheet and in different rows) so that they no longer touched the bottom of line 1 and have not had an issue now for 2 weeks.  (The issue was happening every day the file was used).  I think I suddenly stumbled upon a cure, but time will tell.

Answer (score 0):

I am using excel 2003 on Windows 7. On my laptop left side USB drive G:/ needs something in the root section or all of my Buttons and checkboxes disappear. This happens to all routines written in the last 10 years.

Excel is installed on the C: drive and all files are run and saved there.

My removable drive letters got switch around and so my buttons disappeared when touched and then all of them. I manually set the drive letter of the USB drive back to G:\ and everything appeared as normal with just a few days of panic. A new USB stick in G: will also cause the problem, so whatever is in the root of the old stick I copy over to the new stick. Have not figured out what excel is looking for on the G: drive that causes the images to not show up. I have been to this forum hoping to find an answer over the years so hope this works for someone else.